# How to add currentUser to scope using angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I am using angular-fullstack which comes packed with Authentication already set up. there is a handy function `getCurrentUser()` which allows me to do something like:

```
<input ng-bind="getCurrentUser.name"/>
```

And I will get the name of the active user.

What I would like to do is attach the users name to another object in my scope. Something like this:

```
$scope.activeUser = $scope.getCurrentUser();
```

However I am not sure how to go about joining active user with the getCurrentUser() function.

Answer (score 0):

Define activeUser as an array of elements then add only the ids. When needed do something like this:

```
$scope.activeUser = [];

if (isActive()) {
    var currentUser = $scope.getCurrentUser();

    $scope.activeUser.push(currentUser.id);
}
```

isActive() is a function you should create to define if the user is active or not.
Then you need another condition or a "else" to remove user isn't active anymore.

EDIT: of course you can add the entire object if needed to the array you do that with:

```
  $scope.activeUser[currentUser.id] = currentUser;
```

Then you can get it back on the view with:

```
  <span>{{ activeUser[TheId] }}</span
```

Comment: I tried this:
`$scope.activeUser = [];

  if (isActive()) {
   var currentUser = $scope.getCurrentUser();

   $scope.activeUser.push(currentUser.id);
  }
  
  $log.info($scope.activeUser)`

But I can get it to work it just returns:
`ReferenceError: isActive is not defined`

Comment: I figured it out: 
`$scope.task.createdBy = Auth.getCurrentUser()._id;`

I rather than using `getCurrentUser()` I did `Auth.getCurrentUser()` and injected Auth in to the controller.